# Difference between character_maximum_length and character_octet_length

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, information-schema

Maybe there is an answer for this somewhere but, I couldn't find any efficient answer on Google for this question, therefore, I will ask this here.

I wanted to get some information about my Stored Procedure parameters dynamically, so I wrote this script:

```
SELECT  PARAMETER_NAME,
        DATA_TYPE,
        CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
        CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
WHERE   SPECIFIC_NAME = @ProcName
```

The question is what the difference between CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH and CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH. Could you give me example of when they would have different results?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly, if you're just dealing with SQL Server, [pretend `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` doesn't exist](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views). They're incomplete, documented as unreliable (see the yellow caution signs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)), are not being updated with new features or attributes (e.g. try to find info about filtered indexes or include columns), and don't contain anything you can't get from the `sys` catalog views.

Comment: ...just don't see any good reason to use them when you have to use the catalog views sometimes anyway.

Comment: @AaronBertrand So, if I want to get all parameters of stored procedure, how can I do it?

Comment: sys.parameters?

Comment: @Charles Maybe look at [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx) - the output in system_type_name means you don't have to worry about parens, halving max length for Unicode, etc. etc. Also, once you know int can't take parens, that doesn't seem to be something you need to rely on INFORMATION_SCHEMA for forever. If you're bothering to construct things with dynamic SQL anyway, you can use CASE expressions like the rest of us.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx) CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH is the length in bytes, and CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is the length in characters.

For parameters of type *char* or *varchar* they will be the same, but for parameters of type *nchar* or *nvarchar* they will be different, with OCTET-LENGTH being twice (usually if not always) the CHARACTER_LENGTH.

Comment: When it is not twice the CHARACTER_LENGTH for Unicode strings?

Comment: Check out these two links: http://kunststube.net/encoding/ and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html